# How to add a function in the source of a site through web driver

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Source code contains `<button type="button" onclick="test123()">Click to change the Paragraph from automation</button>` 
I used the code

```
((JavascriptExecutor) this)
                    .executeScript("function test123() { y=document.getElementById('ghi'); y.innerHTML='Automation can change the content';}");
```

But it is not working. Can any suggest the best alternative

Comment: my best alternative to you, would be to not do this.  This goes against the entire principle of test automation.  your tests should be written to automate your web application as your user would do it.  Your users don't edit the code, and switch some innerHTML to make your app work.

Comment: This is not the right thing to do. @sircapsalot is right on the money and I feel his response should be an accepted answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use like this

```
    JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    String  strChange = "function test123(){y=document.getElementById('ghi');y.innerHTML='Automation can change the content';}";
    jse.executeScript(strChange );
```

Enjoy!